The list item width decreases after adding overflow: auto to the list
I have included an example code in which this occurs in the snippet below (look at .list-id):
Problem: the width was set to 220px and in fact it is 71.391px


.featured-products-container {
  display: flex;
}
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px !important;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: max-content;
}
.list-id {
  height: 100%;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 30px 0 0 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.list-title {
  margin: 0;
}
.list-description {
  text-wrap: wrap;
}
.featured-products {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.product {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: blue;
}
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list-id">
      <h3 class="list-title">Products</h3>
      <p class="list-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    </li>
    <ul class="featured-products">
      <li class="product">
      </li>
      <li class="product">
      </li>
      <li class="product">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>



I would be grateful if someone could help me solve this.
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Your HTML is invalid, a ul cannot be a direct child of a ul, it should be inside an li or a separate ul in it's own right.

Flex items are flex-shrink: 1 by default. If that's not what you want, override it.

The problem is your parent ul.list has display: flex. When this is set, the specified width is ignored. You could use flex-basis or move the children into a div and set them as inline elements, which should put them in a row.
